MSPE Calculation Needed for TidySynth
I am trying to figure out what the calculation is for tidysynth when it comes to post mspe and pre mspe. Mostly interested in post mspe though.
This is what my original dataset looks like:
city                 week   sample  passed  pass_rate
<chr>               <date>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
arlington tn    2023-06-18  16241.5 13550.0 0.8342825
arlington tn    2023-06-25  19172.5 16235.5 0.8468118
arlington tn    2023-07-02  13610.5 11466.0 0.8424378
arlington tn    2023-07-09  16900.5 14327.0 0.8477264
arlington tn    2023-07-16  15657.5 13157.5 0.8403321
arlington tn    2023-07-23  16496.0 13899.5 0.8425982

In my dataset there are many 7 cities.
synth_data <- weekly_data %>%
  synthetic_control(outcome = pass_rate, 
                    unit = city, 
                    time = week, 
                    i_unit = "lyndhurst, nj",  # Treated city
                    i_time = as.Date("2024-10-06"),  # Intervention date
                    generate_placebos = TRUE) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = as.Date(c("2023-06-18", "2024-09-29")),
                     Pre_Treatment_Retention = mean(pass_rate)) %>%  # Use outcome variable as predictor
  generate_weights(optimization_window = as.Date(c("2023-06-18", "2024-09-29"))) %>%
  generate_control()

when I run this:
synth_data %>%
  grab_significance()

I am interested in how post_mspe is calculated:
unit_name                type       pre_mspe       post_mspe    mspe_ratio  rank    fishers_exact_pvalue    z_score
<chr>   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
burris - waukesha, wi   Donor   1.371571e-04    3.625624e-05    0.2643409   1   0.1428571   1.2398455
arlington tn            Donor   1.924225e-04    4.736617e-05    0.2461572   2   0.2857143   0.9688800
lyndhurst, nj          Treated  4.005740e-05    8.404384e-06    0.2098085   3   0.4285714   0.4272304
jacksonville, fl        Donor   1.353062e-03    2.792826e-04    0.2064079   4   0.5714286   0.3765559
crystal creek (reno)    Donor   2.145638e-04    2.929985e-05    0.1365555   5   0.7142857   -0.6643513
sacramento, ca          Donor   6.678581e-05    6.955828e-06    0.1041513   6   0.8571429   -1.1472223
ft. worth, tx           Donor   1.474051e-03    1.482107e-04    0.1005465   7   1.0000000   -1.2009383

I attempted this:
results <- synth_data %>% grab_synthetic_control()
in_sample <- results %>% filter(time_unit < as.Date('2024-10-06'))
out_sample <- results %>% filter(time_unit >= as.Date('2024-10-06'))
mean((out_sample$real_y - out_sample$synth_y)^2)
mean((in_sample$real_y - in_sample$synth_y)^2)

However the results do not align
My results:
mean((out_sample$real_y - out_sample$synth_y)^2)
5.615126e-06

Actual = 8.404384e-06

mean((in_sample$real_y - in_sample$synth_y)^2)
4.064594e-05

Actual = 4.005740e-05

If anyone knows the formula for this or if they can produce an example where they use fake data to recreate the output then that would be very helpful!

You were on the right track. It looks like where you differ from their code is that they divide by the number of pre and post periods. I just changed the source code for the grab_significance method which can be found here. For whatever reason you need to arrange it by the mspe ratio to get it to pass the test.
library(tidysynth)
library(tidyverse)

data(smoking)

## all the tidysynth stuff

sig = smoking_out |>
  grab_significance() 

time_window = smoking |>
  distinct(year)|>
  pull(year)

by_hand = smoking_out |>
  grab_synthetic_control(placebo = TRUE) |>
  filter(time_unit %in% time_window) |>
    group_by(.id, period = ifelse(time_unit <= 1988,"pre_mspe","post_mspe")) |>
  summarize(.placebo = mean(.placebo),
   mspe = sum((real_y - synth_y)^2)/dplyr::n(),.groups='drop') |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = period, values_from = mspe) |>
  mutate(mspe_ratio = post_mspe/pre_mspe) |>
  ungroup() |>
  arrange(desc(mspe_ratio)) 

tinytest::expect_identical(by_hand$post_mspe, sig$post_mspe)
#> ----- PASSED      : <-->
#>  call| tinytest::expect_identical(by_hand$post_mspe, sig$post_mspe)

Created on 2024-12-10 with reprex v2.1.1
